# How to create previous and next links for static pages in same folder October cms without plugins

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I have a couple cases pages but I want to add at the end buttons to next and previous case. I don't want to use plugins pages are static. Can you help me please?

Something like

```
<a href="{{ 'cases'|page({ cases_id:+1 }) }}">
    Next case
</a>
<a href="{{ 'cases'|page({ cases_id:-1 }) }}">
    Prev case
</a>
```

If it will good, if `URLs` have names not numbers

[image: Screenshot of category and cases]